# Translated convex sets proof

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let A ⊂ R2 be a fixed convex set and let X1, . . . , Xn ⊂ R2 be any convex sets
such that every three of them intersect a translation of A. Then there exists a translation of A that intersects all sets Xi.

I understood the first two part of the question but I am not able to derive the last part or rather how to prove it. Can someone please help me on how to solve this?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yup, I do know about Helly's theorem in one-dimensional space and in the general case. And I even understand theirs proves. I do know that you have to consider the least maximum endpoints and highest minimum points to prove this case in a general form. But since it's talking about translated one. I am not pretty sure if it will be applied to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by cm(W) the centre of mass of the set W. For every i, define Yi
in such a way that Xi ∩ A' is not equal to φ if and only if cm(A')∈ Yi, for every translation A' of A. Now using Helly’s Theorem we have a point z ∈ Y1 ∩ ... ∩ Yn, we can find a translation A" such that
cm(A") = z. By definition of the sets Yi, the set A" intersects all sets Xi